# Java connection to Object store returning unauthorized 401

Tags: ibm-cloud

i wrote an application to save a file in Object store.
i'm having problems connecting to the object store , when on Bluemix the connection returns an error (AuthenticationException{message=Unauthorized, status=401})

i'm using the openstack4j implementation and this is my code :

```
String envServices = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
    if (envServices != null) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(envServices);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray vcapArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Object-Storage");
        JSONObject vcap = (JSONObject) vcapArray.get(0);
        JSONObject credentials = (JSONObject) vcap.get("credentials");
        username = credentials.get("username").toString();
        password = credentials.get("password").toString();
        auth_url = credentials.get("auth_url").toString() + "/v3";
        domain = credentials.get("domainId").toString();
        project = credentials.get("projectId").toString();
    } else {
        username = "someuser";
        password = "somepassword";
        auth_url = "https://identity.open.softlayer.com";
        domain = "sfsd";
        project = "object_storage_xxxxxxx";
    }
    Identifier domainIdent = Identifier.byName(domain);
    Identifier projectIdent = Identifier.byName(project);


    OSClient os = OSFactory.builderV3().endpoint(auth_url).credentials(username, password,domainIdent).scopeToProject(projectIdent, domainIdent)
            .authenticate();
    objectStorage = os.objectStorage();
    account = objectStorage.account().get();
```

any help will be appreciated.
Assi

Answer (score 0):

Your VCAP_SERVICES is like this:

```
{
"Object-Storage": [
{
  "name": "Object-Storage - YP",
  "label": "Object-Storage",
  "plan": "Free",
  "credentials": {
     "auth_url": "https://identity.open.softlayer.com",
     "project": "object_storage_d049255b",
     "projectId": "0f47b41b06d047f9aae3b33f1db061ed",
     "region": "dallas",
     "userId": "ad78b2a3f843466988afd077731c61fc",
     "username": "user_202db1f8a7aa3f3ac51ec68f10dbe7dc29070bc7",
     "password": "K/jyIi2jR=1?D.TP",
     "domainId": "2df6373c549e49f8973fb6d22ab18c1a",
     "domainName": "639347"
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

So, you have to change this lines:

```
domain = credentials.get("domainId").toString();
project = credentials.get("projectId").toString();
```

with:

```
domain = credentials.get("domainName").toString();
project = credentials.get("project").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will help you to connect Object Storage service to your application

```
String envServices = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

try{

Object obj = parser.parse(envServices);
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray vcapArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Object-Storage");
JSONObject vcap = (JSONObject) vcapArray.get(0);
JSONObject credentials = (JSONObject) vcap.get("credentials");
String userId = credentials.get("userId").toString();
String password = credentials.get("password").toString();
String auth_url = credentials.get("auth_url").toString() + "/v3";
String domain = credentials.get("domainName").toString();
String project = credentials.get("project").toString();
Identifier domainIdent = Identifier.byName(domain);
Identifier projectIdent = Identifier.byName(project);

OSClient os = OSFactory.builderV3()
              .endpoint(auth_url)
              .credentials(userId, password)
              .scopeToProject(projectIdent, domainIdent)
              .authenticate();
SwiftAccount account = os.objectStorage().account().get();

}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line >> `Identifier domainIdent = Identifier.byName(domain);`

It should be like this >> `Identifier domainIdent = Identifier.byId(domain);`
because you are passing Domain ID not Domain name.